# PROC LOESS with option MAXPOINTS = NONE

Tags: sas

I am employing a smoother in order to check how the probability of an event occuring  depends on time

```
ods graphics on; 
proc loess data=final plots(only MAXPOINTS=NONE)=FITPLOT; 
model event = time / smooth=0.66 DEGREE=2; 
run; 
ods graphics off;
```

As one can see Iam using the option MAXPOINTS=NONE , but When the FIT SUMMARY report appears it is given the following:

> FIT METHOD  Kd Tree
>
> NUMBER OF OBSERVATIONS 100500
>
> ...
>
> NUMBER OF FITTING POINTS:  9
>
> ...

What does it mean that it uses 9 fitting points ?

I  would like to use all points (100500) in the smoothing since I specifed MAXPOINTS = NONE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't mean that it used only 9 points in estimating. In essence what it indicates is the optimal  number of points required to come up with the fit. It is likely that your smoothing factor is too high or your data really is truly approximated very well with a 9 - 1 = 8th order polynomial. Try reducing the smoothing factor and this will likely increase the number of fitting points as the order of the polynomial to fit the data will increase.